# Select Specific value from multiple rows returned by Oracle database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, netbeans, oracle11g

I am trying to compare a specific value from the values returned by database.
I am getting multiple rows from `STORESTAFF` but I am trying to compare one of the values returned from the table..

```
contains() and 
equals()
```

are not working.

```
String qry = "Select all employe_id from storestaff where post='Admin'";
pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement(qry);
ResultSet rs2 = pstmnt.executeQuery(qry);
if (rs2.next()) {
    String aa = rs2.getString("employe_id");

    if (aa.contains(UN.getText())) {
        this.aa = aa;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exists");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username doesn't Exist");
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggestt me a better solution for it or can tell me the better solution for it?

Comment: yeah, my prblm has resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `if` it will return the first values, in your case you have to use `while`, which loop throw all the results, so you can check multiple results, instead you can use :

```
boolean check = false;
while (rs2.next()) {
    String aa = rs2.getString("employe_id");
    if (aa.contains(UN.getText())) {
        this.aa = aa;
        check = true;//if the value exist change the variable to true
        break;       //and break the loop
    }
}

//when you end you have to check the value, if true then the user exist else no
if (check) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exists");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username doesn't Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **if(rs2.next())** to w**hile(rs2.next())**  You are getting bulk data, so you need to iterate over it to compare one of the value which you want